# Single entry point by .htaccess show 500 internal error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a single entry point for my custom php mvc application. I'm using apache2 as php server on my ubuntu 14.04 operating system.

My application tree:

localhost/mvc

i. controllers

ii. models

iii. views

iv. webroot

a. index.php
   b. .htaccess

v. .htaccess

My root directory .htaccess code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c >
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And webroot/.htaccess code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT, L]
</IfModule>
```

But it shows as following with 500 status code:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: A 500 error is just a general "something is wrong" type of error. It could mean a thousand things, however the rules are likely your issue. Check your apache error log for more details about what the problem is. It defaults to `/var/log/Apache2/error.log` and would have an actual reason for the error.

Comment: I have tried, but still not working. 500 internal error. Plz, help I'm suffering with it for long hour.

Comment: The log throw the following error:   [Wed Oct 14 03:18:53.569210 2015] [core:alert] [pid 10028] [client ::1:37363] /var/www/html/mvc/.htaccess: <IfModule takes one argument, Container for directives based on existence of specified modules

Comment: There was an white space, I have removed it and then it show the following error:   /var/www/html/mvc/webroot/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: `[PT, L]` => `[PT,L]`

Comment: Hi, great. It works. Please, post it with answer. I'm going to accept it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT, L]
```

As there is a space after `PT,`. `mod_rewrite` syntax is pretty rigid and it doesn't allow unescaped spaces anywhere.

Your `webroot/.htaccess` can be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```